# Adding count column to sql results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create a  column from SQL results that counts the number of duplicate individual result fields within an SQL result set.

Say I have the following data:

```
color    flavor
-----    ------
red      cherry
green    lime
red      strawberry
white    tapioca
blue     blueberry
white    vanilla
```

I would like a result set that would list

```
red      cherry       1
red      strawberry   2
white    vanilla      1
white    tapioca      2
green    lime         1
blue     blueberry    1
```

The order doesn't matter so long as it is grouped by color.  The main issue is getting the third column (count).

I envision doing this by dumping the initial table into a temporary table and then iterating through the table and appending the count column to, maybe, another temp table (insert).

```
declare @color string
declare @flavor string
declare @tmp table (color string, flavor string)
insert @tmp
select color,flavor from menu
select top 1 @color=color, @flavor=flavor from @tmp
while (@@rowcount>0)
begin
  [do stuff here]
  [delete first row of @tmp]
  select top 1 @color=color, @flavor=flavor from @tmp
end
```

I think this is plausible and may be a good direction but I am unsure.  Can anyone provide an alternative and/or fill in the pseudocode to get that third column and delete the first row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using the window funtion `row_number()` :

```
select *, row_number() over (partition by color order by (select null))
from mytable
order by color
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/F_T5jdHc)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted.  Thank you.  I had no idea I was asking for row_number(), nor that it could be used this way.

Comment: Glad to hear :) Yes row_number() is magical